# What does this sign "" mean ? content:""

Tags: html, css, sign

So I was casually looking in inspect element, to try to gather an image from a webpage (https://forsvaret.no/karriere/forstegangstjeneste). The creator of the page had linked to the image through the css ::before selector using ***content: "";*** does anyone know what “” this sign means, and why it have been used ?

This is the Css:

```
.iconForsvaret-fighter::before {
content: ""; 
}
```

And the Html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/karriere/forstegangstjeneste/muligheter/........">
        <span class="iconForsvaret-tank"></span>
        <span>Hæren</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the non-printable character symbol. It is used when you are trying to display a character that is not available in the font being used to render the text.

Most likely that specific character is in the range of Unicode reserved for private use and that there is some code which sets the font for that pseudo-element to one which has a font with characters defined in that range.

Comment: Within the page its the icomoon.io font which has a mapping to that character.

Comment: okey thanks, when i looked inside the code i found that they had a font named **'IconForsvaret'** `font-family: 'IconForsvaret';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;`

Answer (score 0):

"" usually indicates a unicode character that your browser cannot display. It might very well be some sort of emoji from an iphone that your operating system hasn't implemented yet.

Usually upgrading your OS to the latest version fixes those issues.

Answer (score 0):

"" means your font file is missing. when you link you font then show exact font.